# Class/header files - Cannot call member without object

Tags: c++

The base of this code was found in a tutorial, so I'm not quite sure why it is doing this.

The error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:8:32: error: cannot call member function ‘int TestC::getAnswer()’ without object
std::cout << TestC::getAnswer() << std::endl;
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestC.hpp"
int main()
{
    TestC(1, 1);
    std::cout << TestC::getAnswer() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**TestC.cpp**

```
#include "TestC.hpp"
TestC::TestC(int x, int y)
{
    gx = x;
    gy = y;
}

int TestC::getSum()
{
    return gx + gy;
}
```

**TestC.hpp**

```
#ifndef TestC_H
#define TestC_H

class TestC
{
    int gx;
    int gy;
public:
    TestC(int x, int y);
    int getAnswer();
};

#endif
```

This is how I am compiling:

```
g++ main.cpp -o Main
```

Comment: In order for `TestC::getAnswer()` to work, `getAnswer()` would have to be a `static` member of the `TestC` class.

Comment: So I changed `int getAnswer();` to `static int getAnswer();` and it still does not work. It just gives me similar errors for both TestC::TestC() and TestC::getAnswer() for undefined reference.

Comment: Well read this, you should get the idea, how things are supposed to look. http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/

Comment: I think I have the just of it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not creating an object just by calling the constructor. You'd have to actually declare an object

```
TestC myC{1, 1};
int answer = myC.getAnswer();
```

So your `main` function would change to

```
int main()
{
    TestC myC{1, 1};
    std::cout << myC.getAnswer() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a question about the {}, are they always needed because it's a constructor?

Comment: You could also have written `TestC myC = TestC(1,1);` which is also fine. You just need to be careful about things like `TestC myC();` which will actually produce a [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) by declaring a new function, rather than calling the default constructor. I just use the initializer list syntax `{}` to make sure I don't run into that.